# Is it possible to have Haml indent HTML generated by a view helper in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Say I have a things resource with a view helper method such as:

```
module ThingsHelper
  def foo
    ret = ""
    3.times { ret += content_tag(:li, "foo") }
    content_tag(:ul, ret)
  end
end
```

This, then, is used in a template:

```
%p
  = foo
```

The HTML source that's generated looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Foo</title>
    </head>
</html>
<body>
    <p>
        <ul><li>foo</li><li>foo</li><li>foo</li></ul>
    </p>
</body>
```

As you can see, the helper output is not indented as the rest of the code. Any way to remedy this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try out the [`haml_tag` helper method](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method) provided with Haml. It's like `content_tag` in some ways, but it outputs properly indented HTML. The main difference is that it outputs directly to the template, rather than returning a string. For example:

```
module ThingsHelper
  def foo
    haml_tag :ul do
      3.times { haml_tag(:li, "foo") }
    end
  end
end
```

(As a side note, it's considered very bad Ruby style to use something other than two spaces for indentation).

Comment: Worked great. Blogged a simple example with a formatter for tree-structured collections at: http://tumblr.com/xq73f3ypd

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it - at least not without a significant amount of mucking around.

Your `= foo` is simply printing what is returned by your `foo` helper - it's not getting parsed by haml. And you can't write haml in your helper method either.

The simplest way I can think of to deal with this is to just add literal whitespace characters in your helper (ie `\n` and `\t`).

You could also `require` the relevant haml class(es) in your helper and call the parsing methods manually on `ret`, but this is probably more complicated than worthwhile.