# Is it possible to indent HTML generated by a view helper in Rails using ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm using Rails 3.2.x with ERB. I created a builder using helper methods like `content_tag`. But the output is all concatenated on a single line.

Someone asked the same question but with HAML : [Is it possible to have Haml indent HTML generated by a view helper in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528166/is-it-possible-to-have-haml-indent-html-generated-by-a-view-helper-in-rails).

For example, in my helper:

```
def foo
  content_tag :div do
    content_tag :div do
      content_tag :span, "test"
    end
  end
end
```

In my erb:

```
<%= foo %>
```

The result is:

```
<div><div><span>test</span></div></div>
```

And I'd like to have:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since I'm quite new to Rails, I may be missing something obvious, but I couldn't find anything on the Internet...

Thanks